# Cannot Insert Image In To Static Block

Tags: static-block

I need to change the front banner of my site, but the button to "Insert Image" in to the static block does nothing when you click it. None of the buttons do.

I also wanted to make a coupon code and when I tried to click to make the rule that button now also does nothing.

I notice at the bottom of my browser this comes up - javascript:void(0) when trying to do the coupons, but not when trying to change the image.

Our web designer has recently been making changes to the site to speed things up a bit but these buttons seem not to be working ever since he's been doing so.

So my question I suppose is - has he messed up somewhere? Or is there an issue in Magento that I've missed that will fix this?

It's Black Friday tomorrow so getting the site updated is quite important!

Many Thanks.

Comment: if you can't find a workaround consider changing directly via DB

Comment: Open the firebug and check whether you are seeing any JS error in the console when you click on the button.

Comment: Thanks for your replies but I'm not sure how to do any of that! Coding etc is usually left to our web guy... we just use the static blocks etc.

Do you think this could be a mistake his end? Or is magento misbehaving?

Comment: Our web guy supplied me with the FTP details so I can work around this now. Thanks guys.

Worryingly he's struggling to work out why it's happened in the first place though!